# Array From database

Tags: php, mysql, database, arrays

I'm not keen on how to make an array from database.  Tried to avoid learning those but apparently it's in need for now.

Basically my database is structured with millions of rows.  Player Name and Snap (Unix TimeStamp) are usually "duplicated" but with different data in those rows (city, x, y, etc).

Ideally, trying to figure out HOW to make an array via `SELECT` statement, something like:

Output, I would like would be something like:
Name = Snap => (how many city on those day), Snap => (how many city on another day).. so on..

Question here is, what's the proper array "command" (if you call that) to pull the name ONCE and pull multiple snap with the counts based on the snap.

My SELECT goes:

```
// SELECT count(*), player, snap
// FROM DB WHERE GROUP BY snap, player ORDER BY snap, player DESC
while ($row = fetch_assoc($Result) {
     // How you go about putting array here?
}
```

Comment: Sorry for not being clear here.  I know about SELECT statement and how to open/close, etc.

What I am asking is how to CREATE an array (never done it before).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the comment about needing to read up a little more on the basics, but you can do something like the following, to create your multidimensional array:

```
<?php

$results = array();

$Result = 'SELECT count(*),player,snap FROM DB WHERE GROUP BY snap,player ORDER BY snap,player DESC';
while ($row = fetch_assoc($Result){
  if (!isset($results[$row['player']][$row['snap']]) {
    $results[$row['player']][$row['snap']] = 0;
  }
  $results[$row['player']][$row['snap']] += $row['count(*)']; 
}

?>
```

Comment: now THIS is what Im looking for, now to try to understand what has been done.  Thanks for leading me to the right direction! :)

Answer (score 2):

It'll be done like this:

```
$Result = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) as count, player,
     snap FROM DB GROUP BY snap, player ORDER BY snap, player DESC");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($Result) {
  print_r( $row );
  echo "This is the count value -> " . $row['count'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these first:-

1. http://phpsense.com/2006/php-mysql/
2. http://www.freewebmasterhelp.com/tutorials/phpmysql

You need basics on SQL as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
$sql = "SELECT count(*) as count, player,
        snap FROM DB GROUP BY snap, player ORDER BY snap, player DESC";

/* Connect To Database */
$mysqli = new mysqli ( "localhost", "username", "password", "database" );

/* check connection */
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf ( "Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error );
    exit ();
}

$result = $mysqli->query ( $sql );
$array = array();
if ($result) {
    while ( $row = $mysqli->fetch_assoc ( $result ) ) {
        $array[$row['player']] += $row['count'];
    }

    print_r($array); // Return array
}
```